# Multiple joins from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using SQL Server and I'm having a difficult time trying to get the results from a SELECT query.

I have 6 tables:

- `Product`
- `Market`
- `Seller`
- `Buyer`
- `Customer` (data about customers - buyers and sellers)
- `Currency`

```
select * from Product;
```

```
id(PK) | name_product
-------+--------------
1      | apple
2      | orange
3      | juice
```

```
select * from Market;
```

```
OrderID(PK)   |SellOrderID(FK) | BuyOrderID(FK) | product-id
--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------
45            | 5              | 15             | 1
46            | 3              | 36             | 3
58            | 4              | 8              | 2
```

```
select * from Seller;
```

```
SellOrderID   |id_seller(PK) | id_product 
--------------+--------------+---------------------
5             | 5            | 1
3             | 3            | 3
4             | 2            | 2
```

```
select * from Buyer;
```

```
BuyOrderID    |id_Buyer(PK)  | id_product 
--------------+--------------+---------------------
15            | 1            | 1
36            | 4            | 3
8             | 6            | 2
```

```
select * from Customer;
```

```
id_customer(PK) | name_customer
----------------+---------------
1               | Alice
2               | Sam
3               | Katy
4               | Soul
5               | Fab
6               | Yas
```

```
select * from Currency;
```

```
id_product(PK,FK) | currency(PK)
------------------*-------------
1                 | EUR
2                 | USD
3                 | EUR
```

I'm looking to select the name of customers, their orders, the name of product bought and sold and the currency given to each product.

But I am not getting correct result. I want results as shown below:

```
name_customer  | OrderID  | name_product | currency(PK)     
---------------+----------+--------------+-------------
Alice          |  45       | apple        | EUR             
Sam            |  58       | juice        | EUR
Katy           |  46       | orange       | USD
Soul           |  46       | apple        | EUR             
Fab            |  45       | juice        | EUR
Yas            |  58       | orange       | USD
```

Please advise

Comment: What is your attempt so far? If you show us that, we'll have a much easier time correcting your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.name_customer
,m.OrderID
,p.name_product
,cc.currency
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Buyer b ON b.id_Buyer = c.id_customer
INNER JOIN Market m ON m.BuyOrderID = b.BuyOrderID
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.id = m.product-id
INNER JOIN Currency cc ON cc.id_product = p.id
```

Hopefully it should work! If not please let me know.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to include product id in the join between buyer and market otherwise you could end up with a many-to-many cartesian product should a buyer buy more than one product on a single buy order. It works fine in OPs example, but may break down with more real-life data.  (but perhaps this is a homework question... who knows). At any rate, the inclusion of product id on three different tables redundantly leads me to believe that it may be part of the key to join across `market`.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help! The orders concern both buyers and sellers but in your query I only find a join on the buyers table. Can you please explain your logic ? Much appreciated

Comment: As per your result,

Comment: Each matched order, have a sellID and buyID ( table market , table seller, table buyer ) so each sellerID and buyerID have orders in their basket. Then, each buyer and seller have a correspending name in table customer.

Comment: As per your result, Lets consider the first row.
We can conclude that Alice ordered 'apple', with orderID 45 and paid in 'EUR' currency. These values matches only when we consider Buyer table and Market table with the same BuyOrderID (value 15) which gives the orderID as 45 on Market table and it aligns with Alice data.

Comment: Yes and for the example that you've mentionned we need to consider row 5 as well : Fab            |  45       | juice        | EUR 
because Fab sold 'apple', with orderID 45 to be paid in 'EUR' currency.